# Matching logo sizes

Tags: logo, resize, dimensions

When you're designing a document and you have to place a bunch of logo endorsements in the document, how do you make all the logos seem the same size?

Is there a more mathematical or scientific way of matching logo sizes other than using your eye?

I am contemplating on using the area size of each logo, but Adobe Illustrator has no way to resize logos according to their area size, you can only resize logos according to their width or height dimensions. The actual area size has to be calculated and it becomes messy and complicated.

Comment: Illustrator can tell you the area of an object (via script property area). However the eye does emphasize edges so a object with a lot of edges can be more visible,

Answer (score 0):

You have a set of logos you want to display with equal emphasis.
Take the most compact shape, a solid circle, to use as your reference.
Match the other logo sizes to it.

Here a lot of squinting and estimating come into play.

Tall thin logos need to be taller than the circle.

Short, wide logos need to be wider than the circle.

Solid black logos need to be a little smaller.

Wispy, wiry logos need to be a little bigger.

Lean back in your chair and squint your eyes at your screen until the grid of logos is a blur. Use this view to make their relative sizes appear equal.

Type making tricks come into play, where pointed shapes like a capital A are taller than blocky shapes like a capital E.

Comment: YOu dont have to lean back just blur and zoom out :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Indesign CC you can utilize the LIBRARIES. So, determine the size you would like the logo to appear on ALL pages and places in document and drag and drop to your opened LIBRARY window. You will then be able to grab from the library and drop into your document or ANY document, it will always be that size! You can even do several sizes and put them under different titles in the library, ie. large logos, and tagline logos.